# Como garantir segurança de api's rest

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, rest

Estou criando um sistem utilizando a MEAN Stack e me surgiu uma dúvida ..

Minha aplicação client em angular faz uma solicitação para a api ex:
POST http://127.0.0.1/api/produto

Se algum usuário mal intencionado encontrar a url da api ele poderia fazer um post sem passar pelo client da minha aplicação por exemplo, tem alguma forma de evitar/contornar isso ? Tipo fazer com que as requisições para a minha api fossem feitas somente do client que eu permitir ?

Comment: Geralmente você cria um hash que funcione apenas para aquela sessão, só que isso implica em não deixar sua aplicação RESTFul que é o padrão que impede que você tenha qualquer controle de sessão

Comment: Dê uma pesquisada em como funciona o padrão de autentificação **OAuth2**, é a solução mais utilizada para garantir o acesso à seus recursos de forma segura.